# How can I get my external links to trigger click events on cooresponding google map markers?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Im trying to figure out how I can have the links that appear in the external div trigger click events on the corresponding map marker (opening the info window).  I think my code is solid (except maybe where I tried copying the array of location data to get the click function to be able to access the array given the scope hurdles i ran into - Im just not sure what to do to get it to work right.  Can anyone shed any light on what I need to modify in my code? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var gmarkers = []; 

function initialize() {
var locations = [
         ['DESCRIPTION', 41.926979, 12.517385, 3],
         ['DESCRIPTION', 41.914873, 12.506486, 2],
         ['DESCRIPTION', 61.918574, 12.507201, 1]
    ];




    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });



    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


    // CREATE THE MARKERS ON THE MAP FROM THE ARRAY DATA
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

    gmarkers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    // ADD A LINK FOR THIS MARKER TO THE DIV, WHEN CLICKED, IT SHOULD TRIGGER THE MARKER CLICK / INFO WINDOW FOR COORESPONDING MARKER
    $('#listdiv').append('<p><a href="javascript:show(' + i + ')" id="link' + i + '">' + locations[i][0] + '</a>');


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

}

map.fitBounds(bounds);

var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
    //map.setZoom(10); // NO LONGER NEED, SINCE FITBOUNDS SCALES VIEW TO SHOW ALL MARKERS?
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
});

}

// THIS FUNCTION IS SUPPOSED TO BE CALLED ON THE EXTERNAL LINK CLICKS - SHOULD OPEN THE COORESPONDING MARKER/INFO WINDOW.
function show(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
    alert("I see a click.");

}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize();" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
    <div id="listdiv" style="width:100%; border: 2px solid blue; color: black; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an error on the console log? Are you sure the jquery library is included? Check the src attribute, it misses the http: part

Comment: I really don't understand what you are doing with gmarkers. You should have the markers there, not a concatenation of the locations array.

Comment: @alkis the jquery library should be fine - i am using whats listed here: [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)... I could even remove that for now - my focus now is just getting the external links to work and trigger the marker click.  the locations array is where the marker / info window data comes from -- works fine, i tested/added gmarkers array (a copy of locations array) to just try to access the data since i had scope issues and the function for external link clicks couldnt 'see' the array data.  so gmarkers was just from my testing, thats all.

Comment: @alkis no error on console at all.

Comment: In most examples the gmarkers array is an array of google.maps.Marker objects.  If you are going to trigger a click event on an element of that array, that is what it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
gmarkers = locations.concat();
```

add this line after you create the marker:

```
gmarkers.push(marker);
```

Comment: Thanks.  worked like a charm.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That's what I was talking about in my second comment.