# Center and open InfoWindow with array in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the below code running to show markers on a map in an array thats separate from my GeoLocation marker. It's easy to make a simple external link but how do I create the same in array markers, also any reason why this doesn't work in IE?

**JS:**

```
//Retina Images
var RetinaHotelMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker_hotel@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));
var RetinaChurchMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker_church@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));
var RetinaCrosshair = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker_crosshair@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));
var RetinaMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./assets/images/global/global_marker@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30,30));

//Markers
var markers = [
    [1, 'Great Fosters', 51.416741,-0.543854, RetinaHotelMarker],
    [2, 'St Matthews', 51.432327,-0.459162, RetinaChurchMarker],
    // Staines
    [3, 'Travel Lodge Staines', 51.435698,-0.514469, RetinaMarker]
];

// Geolocation Success
function success(position) {

// Create Canvas
var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
mapcanvas.id = 'global_map_container';
document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

// Map Options
var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    //center: coords,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.416741,-0.543854),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// Create Map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("global_map_container"), options);

// Marker Control
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// Marker Creation
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]),
        map: map,
        flat: true,
        icon: markers[i][4]
    });

    // Find Bounds  
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

    // Marker Center
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            // Center on marker
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][1]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

// Make Map fit all Markers
map.fitBounds(bounds);

// Get Geolocation Lat/Lng
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

// Create Geolocation Marker
var GeoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coords,
    map: map,
    icon:RetinaCrosshair,
    title:"You are here!",
});

//Button Controls
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("Map_GeoLocation"),"click", function() { 
    map.setCenter(GeoMarker.getPosition() );
});

}

// Run GeoLocation check
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="Map_GeoLocation" class="global_crosshair"><span>Find Me</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Map_Church" class="global_church"><span>The Church</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Map_Hotel"class="global_hotel"><span>The Venue</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my external links to trigger click events on cooresponding google map markers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265946/how-can-i-get-my-external-links-to-trigger-click-events-on-cooresponding-google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of google.maps.Markers (in the global scope), trigger a 'click' event on the appropriate marker

```
// Marker Creation
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]),
        map: map,
        flat: true,
        icon: markers[i][4]
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);

    // Find Bounds  
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

    // Marker Center
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            // Center on marker
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][1]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Then to click on the first marker:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[0],'click');
```

Comment: How do I run this code? Ive tried adding an onclick="google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[0],'click');" to the link but safari error console returns "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: gmarkers"

Comment: Did you create a gmarkers array in the global scope? (HTML click handlers run in the global scope)

Comment: I don't understand, the code is in a separate script in the <head> tag but another error I have noticed is when I add "gmarkers.push(marker);" only the first marker is shown on the map, you can view this at www.everythingcreative.co.uk/marker

Comment: That error message means that gmarkers is not declared.  You need to add "var gmarkers = [];" to your code.

Comment: I'm such an idiot! Totally forgot to declare the var!! Thank you, works perfectly now.